# Comentário amarelo no PyCharm ao utilizar o termo "todo"

Tags: python, pycharm

Gostaria de saber porque meu comentário fica com a cor amarela. Isso sempre acontece quando utilizo a palavra 'todo'.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seu editor interpreta "todo" como uma marcação de algo pendente, algo a fazer - em inglês "to do". É comum usar TODO em comentário para indicar pendências.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é devido às configurações do PyCharm, que considera o termo "todo" como *to do*, do inglês "a fazer" e destaca o conteúdo como forma de alertar o desenvolvedor sobre as pendências.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Inclusive você pode configurar o comportamento do editor em relação a isso nesta parte.

Tal ferramenta pode ser utilizada, inclusive, quando for fazer algum *commit* através do próprio *software*, te dando a opção de verificar se não ficou nenhuma pendência no código antes de versioná-lo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Isso não tem a ver com a linguagem - (código fonte não tem "cores" é só texto, de qualquer forma) -  e sim, com a ferramenta que você está usando - no caso o PyCharm.

O PyCharm é uma IDE, e IDEs provem suporte para escrever projetos grandes que vão além da linguagem em si. No caso, o qu efaz com que a cor seja mudada é que há uma prática entre desenvolvedores de colocar palavras chave em alguns comentários indicando pontos importantes que devem ser revisitados mais pra frente no projeto.

Um exemplo disso é a palavra "FIXME" (conserte-me) e no seu caso, o uso de "TODO" - "To Do"  - significando "ainda falta fazer (isso)"  - o PyCharm então destaca os comentários que tem lembretes do desenvolvedor de "coisas que faltam serem feitas".

Para a linguagem em si, é só um comentário, ignorado como qualquer outro.